# My slider refuses to slide, it just vanishes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css-animations, slide

Here's my problem: I have an image slider that's refusing to actually slide. I've spent the last two hours browsing answers here, and looking at JSFiddles. Nothing seems to be of any help.

This is my problem: I have an HTML table contained within a div, with given properties below. When the button at the top is clicked, the slider (the div with id "slider") is supposed to toggle via a slide animation. But instead, it appears or disappears without an animation!

I've made sure it has a height and width, and everything else that various answers said it needs (though if I didn't have to define a height and width in px, thus letting it expand or contract to however large or small it needs to be, would be great). But yet there's no animation! It just disappears!

Please help!

Also, most of the HTML is the table which you can ignore. Just the beginning and end are important.

```
<h2><strong>SPRING CONVENTION SCHEDULE OF EVENTS</strong></h2>
<br>
<button id="toggleSwitch" onClick="toggleFlipFlop();">Click here to show table</button>

<!--table for Friday events-->
<div id = "slider" class="hidden">
<table id="friday-table">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th colspan="2"><strong>SCHEDULE OF EVENTS FOR FRIDAY, MARCH 31</strong></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3:45 - 5:00</td>
<td>CONVENTION REGISTRATION</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>4:30 - 5:15</td>
<td>GRAPHIC ARTS REGISTRATION</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>4:30 - 4:50</td>
<td>CANDIDATES MEETING</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>5:15 - 5:25</td>
<td>SPIRIT COMPETITION</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>5:25 - 6:00</td>
<td>GENERAL ASSEMBLY</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>7:00 - 9:00</td>
<td>COSTUME CONTEST</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>7:30 - 9:00</td>
<td>SKIT CONTEST</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>7:15 - 8:00</td>
<td>ESSAY CONTEST</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>8:00 - 8:30</td>
<td>IMPROMPTU ART</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>8:00 - 9:30</td>
<td>SERVICE PROJECT</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>8:00 - 9:30</td>
<td>BOARD GAMES</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<!--table for Saturday events-->
<table id="saturday-table">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th colspan="2"><strong>SCHEDULE OF EVENTS FOR SATURDAY, APRIL 1</strong></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>8:00 - 9:00</td>
<td>SCRAPBOOK CHECK-IN</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>8:00 - 9:00</td>
<td>GRAPHIC ARTS</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>8:15 - 8:45</td>
<td>CONVENTION REGISTRATION AND SATURDAY CHECK-IN</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>9:00 - 10:00</td>
<td>ACADEMIC TESTING (all levels)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>10:15 - 10:45</td>
<td>SEMINAR SESSION I</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>10:30 - 12:30</td>
<td>DRAMATIC INTERPRETATION</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>10:30 - 11:00</td>
<td>MIDDLE SCHOOL CERTAMEN FINALS</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>11:00 - 11:30</td>
<td>SEMINAR SESSION II</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>11:00 - 11:30</td>
<td>ADVANCED CERTAMEN FINALS</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>11:30 - 12:00</td>
<td>INTERMEDIATE CERTAMEN FINALS</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>12:00 - 12:30</td>
<td>NOVICE CERTAMEN FINALS</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>12:30 - 3:00</td>
<td>GRAPHIC ARTS VIEWING</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>12:45 - 1:30</td>
<td>"MEET THE CANDIDATES" MEETING</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1:00 - 2:30</td>
<td>LATIN SIGHT READING</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1:00 - 2:30</td>
<td>ENGLISH ORATORY</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1:00 - 2:30</td>
<td>OPEN CERTAMEN</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1:30 - 2:30</td>
<td>OLYMPIKA I</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2:00</td>
<td>VOTING BALLOTS DUE</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3:00 - 4:00</td>
<td>OLYMPIKA II</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3:00 - 3:30</td>
<td>CHARIOT RACING AND CATAPULT</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3:00 - 3:30</td>
<td>GRAPHIC ARTS PICKUP</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>4:20 - 4:30</td>
<td>SPIRIT COMPETITION</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>4:30 - 5:00</td>
<td>CLOSING GENERAL ASSEMBLY</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
#slider{
height: 1530px;
width: 524.317px;
transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}
.hidden{
    height: 0;
}
```

And the JS:

```
//script for slide down reveal for table 
//to avoid taking up too much space 
function toggleFlipFlop() {
    var toggleSwitch = $("#toggleSwitch");
    var slider = $("#slider");
    console.log("HTML elements translated to objects");
    function slideMe(slider) {
        slider.toggleClass("hidden");
        console.log("hidden class toggled");
    };
    console.log("SlideMe() successfully defined");
    toggleSwitch.onclick = slideMe(slider); 
    console.log("onclick attribute of toggleswitch set");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're over complicating. You use an inline `onClick` that calls a function that instantiates a function that calls again a click on the same button... **ehh**

Also, since you cannot reliably animate/toggle height in CSS3 use jQuery `slideToggle()`

```js
function toggleFlipFlop() {
  $("#slider").slideToggle(1000);
}


// REMOVE inline JS: onClick="toggleFlipFlop();"
// and use this:
$("#toggleSwitch").on("click", toggleFlipFlop);
```

```css
#slider {
  height: 1530px;
  width: 524.317px;
  /*transition: all 1s ease-in-out; you cannot use this I'm sorry. */
}

.hidden {
  display: none; /* use this instead */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2><strong>SPRING CONVENTION SCHEDULE OF EVENTS</strong></h2>
<br>
<button id="toggleSwitch">Click here to show table</button>

<!--table for Friday events-->
<div id="slider" class="hidden">
  <table id="friday-table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2"><strong>SCHEDULE OF EVENTS FOR FRIDAY, MARCH 31</strong></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3:45 - 5:00</td>
        <td>CONVENTION REGISTRATION</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4:30 - 5:15</td>
        <td>GRAPHIC ARTS REGISTRATION</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4:30 - 4:50</td>
        <td>CANDIDATES MEETING</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5:15 - 5:25</td>
        <td>SPIRIT COMPETITION</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5:25 - 6:00</td>
        <td>GENERAL ASSEMBLY</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7:00 - 9:00</td>
        <td>COSTUME CONTEST</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7:30 - 9:00</td>
        <td>SKIT CONTEST</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7:15 - 8:00</td>
        <td>ESSAY CONTEST</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>8:00 - 8:30</td>
        <td>IMPROMPTU ART</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>8:00 - 9:30</td>
        <td>SERVICE PROJECT</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>8:00 - 9:30</td>
        <td>BOARD GAMES</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!--table for Saturday events-->
  <table id="saturday-table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2"><strong>SCHEDULE OF EVENTS FOR SATURDAY, APRIL 1</strong></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>8:00 - 9:00</td>
        <td>SCRAPBOOK CHECK-IN</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>8:00 - 9:00</td>
        <td>GRAPHIC ARTS</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>8:15 - 8:45</td>
        <td>CONVENTION REGISTRATION AND SATURDAY CHECK-IN</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>9:00 - 10:00</td>
        <td>ACADEMIC TESTING (all levels)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>10:15 - 10:45</td>
        <td>SEMINAR SESSION I</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>10:30 - 12:30</td>
        <td>DRAMATIC INTERPRETATION</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>10:30 - 11:00</td>
        <td>MIDDLE SCHOOL CERTAMEN FINALS</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>11:00 - 11:30</td>
        <td>SEMINAR SESSION II</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>11:00 - 11:30</td>
        <td>ADVANCED CERTAMEN FINALS</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>11:30 - 12:00</td>
        <td>INTERMEDIATE CERTAMEN FINALS</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>12:00 - 12:30</td>
        <td>NOVICE CERTAMEN FINALS</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>12:30 - 3:00</td>
        <td>GRAPHIC ARTS VIEWING</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>12:45 - 1:30</td>
        <td>"MEET THE CANDIDATES" MEETING</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1:00 - 2:30</td>
        <td>LATIN SIGHT READING</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1:00 - 2:30</td>
        <td>ENGLISH ORATORY</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1:00 - 2:30</td>
        <td>OPEN CERTAMEN</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1:30 - 2:30</td>
        <td>OLYMPIKA I</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2:00</td>
        <td>VOTING BALLOTS DUE</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3:00 - 4:00</td>
        <td>OLYMPIKA II</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3:00 - 3:30</td>
        <td>CHARIOT RACING AND CATAPULT</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3:00 - 3:30</td>
        <td>GRAPHIC ARTS PICKUP</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4:20 - 4:30</td>
        <td>SPIRIT COMPETITION</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4:30 - 5:00</td>
        <td>CLOSING GENERAL ASSEMBLY</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Yep. You cannot transition `height` reliably in CSS3. (min-height eventually, but even than it's not perfect)

Comment: The problem with that solution is it'll leave a big blank spot on my site where the slider is supposed to go, which I can't have. That's why I have to transition the height.